# What is the intent to choose playlist from google play music

Tags: android, google-play

I have a button, if user click it, will launch the playlist screen of google play music, the user can choose one playlist, then go back to my app, I can get the data of the playlist which was chose by user.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Where is your Question mark?

Comment: @toha I want to choose a playList from google play music like use intent to pick a contact number, but I don't know how to do that with google music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do that. Google Play Music does not offer an API.